# OOP: instantiating a class containing a console method within a main method using C#?

Tags: c#, oop

In the C# code below, I am trying to execute the code in the `consoleread` method by instantiating it within the `Main` method. I am a complete beginner at OOP and it seems to work but I just want to be sure if this is the right way to do it?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class ConsoleRead
    {
        public void consoleread()
        {
            string[] sPorts = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            foreach (string port in sPorts)
            {
                var serialPort = new SerialPort();
                serialPort.PortName = port;
                serialPort.Open();
                serialPort.WriteLine("ATI");
                var message = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConsoleRead c = new ConsoleRead();
            c.consoleread();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's alright. You have a class with an instance method, so you instantiate that class and call the method against the instance.

Now, for the question "is this the right way to do", then it's a little hard to answer without more background. In your particular example, if the only goal of your application is to write some string on serial ports without any reusability concerns, then creating a class that is instantiated only once is probably useless, you should just move the code from your `consoleread` method to the `main` method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its the right way. But are you facing any problems in it?

Comment: Thank you. I am facing an exception maybe I should post it in a different question? I just wanted to check if I got OOP right.

Comment: @arthurmani: What exception are you getting and do you get that exception at runtime or compiletime?

Comment: The exception is: `The device is not connected` and i get it at compile time.

Comment: @arthurmani: That exception has nothing to do with OOPS. I have written your code and it is working fine.